# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'toMap' in Symbol(react.element) error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

i'm using a resolver function. This function returns an object whose values is an error message: This is the code:

```
const codeErrors = ({ code }) => {
  if (code === '1111') {
    return {
      'contact1': (
        <ErrorWrapper id={code} />
      )
    };
  }
return {
    'contact2': (
      <ErrorWrapper id={code} />
    )
  };
```

The ErrorWraper component is just a react component with this code:

```
const ErrorWrapperComponent = ({ id, locale, serverErrorMessages, values, defaultMessage }) => (
  id ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      {console.log(id)}
      <FormattedMessage
        id={id}
        values={values}
        defaultMessage={defaultMessage || `${CLIENT_ERROR_MESSAGES[locale].generalError} (${id})`}
      />
      {serverErrorMessages && serverErrorMessages[id] && ` (${id})`}
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : null
);
```

But when it's rendered the error Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'toMap' in Symbol(react.element) is appeared countless time. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla:

> The in operator can only be used to check if a property is in an
>   object. You can't search in strings, or in numbers, or other primitive
>   types.

```
"Hello" in "Hello World"; 
// TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Hello' in 'Hello World'
```

Instead you will need to use String.prototype.indexOf(), for example.

```
"Hello World".indexOf("Hello") !== -1; 
// true
```